# Create line graph from dataframe with row values as the value

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have the below (see pic) dataframe and would like to create a graph in which the x-axis is the days of the month (currently the column name) and the values are the value in the row corresponding to the timeframe. Further, I would like each line to represent a ticker(TSLA, MSFT, etc).

I was planning to use plotly, but am open to other libraries which can do this. My current code is:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.line(df_mentioned,  x=['1-10_Ap','21-31_Ap','1-10_May','11-20_May','21-31_May','1-10_June','11-20_June','21-30_June'], color ='Term')
fig.show()
```

[image: image of df]

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the official reference, the format of the data to draw a line graph is vertical. You will need to process the data you present into a vertical Kaga. Once the data is in vertical, your graphing code can be utilized.

```
df.set_index(['Term','Company_Name'], inplace=True)
df = df.stack().reset_index()
df.columns = ['Term', 'Company_Name', 'date', 'value']
df.head()
    Term    Company_Name    date    value
0   TSLA    Tesla Inc. Common Stock     1-10_May    237
1   TSLA    Tesla Inc. Common Stock     11-20_May   77
2   TSLA    Tesla Inc. Common Stock     21-31_May   127
3   TSLA    Tesla Inc. Common Stock     1-10_Ap     56
4   TSLA    Tesla Inc. Common Stock     11-20_Ap    151

import plotly.express as px
fig = px.line(df,  x='date', y='value', color='Term')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer